# Why can't connect ftp server in android phone from pc?

Tags: ftp

I have built ftp server in my Galaxy S20 FE 5G with Cx File Explorer:

[image]

Now i want to connect the ftp from pc with file explorer:

[image]

How can connect it with some software or command line?

My pc's internal ip address is :

```
#execute on my pc
sudo ifconfig
enp2s0: flags=-28605<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.31.39  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        inet6 fe80::8e0:afff:fef4:4759  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
```

Scan my phone from pc :

```
sudo nmap 192.168.31.46 -p 2780
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-03-09 23:03 HKT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.31.46
Host is up (0.20s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
2780/tcp filtered lbc-control
MAC Address: AA:BA:71:96:48:49 (Unknown)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.31 seconds
```

Comment: The address you entered seems wrong. It should be: `ftp://192.168.31.39:2780`. Then, a window will prompt you to enter the username and password. Or download Filezilla and use it to connect to the phone.